# Unable to access the HTML text box placed inside LiteralControl in Gridview ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, literals

I have a gridview in which there are number of columns having item template (added from code behind). The number of columns will be dynamic. Item template may contain text box in several condition. In the submit button's click event when I want to access it I am not able to access it.

My code for adding the template is as below:

```
if (showBlankTextBox == true)
{

    (c as LiteralControl).ID = "ltr_" + fieldName;
    (c as LiteralControl).Text = "<label>" + targetValue + "</label>" +
    "<br /> " +
    "<input type='textbox' id='txt_" + fieldName + "' cols='10' runat='server' />";
//   "<asp:TextBox ID='txt_" + fieldName + "' runat='server'></asp:TextBox>";
}
else
{
    (c as LiteralControl).Text = "<label>" + targetValue + "</label>" +
                                    "<br/> <div> <label>" + actualValue + "</label> </div>" +
                                    "<div>" + percentResult + "</div>";
}
```

After using this code I am getting the below GridView which is absolutely perfect

[image]

In above image, red squared area is text box which is placed inside the `LiteralControl` and the HTML generated for the text box is `<input type="textbox" id="txt_9_Q" cols="10" runat="server">` (I inspected this HTML from firebug).

In the click event of submit button I want to access the text box value but I am not able to find the text box control. My code for accessing the text box is as below:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // getting data table from gridview
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)grdKPI.DataSource;

    string strActualValue = string.Empty;

    foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grdKPI.Rows)
    {
        LiteralControl txtQuarter = gridRow.Cells.Cast<TableCell>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Controls.Cast<LiteralControl>().Any(ctrl => ctrl.GetType() == typeof(LiteralControl))).Controls.Cast<LiteralControl>().FirstOrDefault(ctr => ctr.GetType() == typeof(LiteralControl));

        if (txtQuarter != null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

aspx code for gridview is as per below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Area" HeaderText="Area" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Purpose" HeaderText="Purpose"/>            
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But in the text property of `txtQuarter` I am not seeing the text box.

What am I missing?

Comment: post the aspx code for the gridview

Comment: Hello Sir, 
I have updated my question.@user3240361

Comment: Are you trying to get text value of `txtQuarter` ? What about simply using `row.Cells[2].Text;` ???

Comment: @MohemmadK you will not be able to access the value of server control created dynamically in the code behind.  What you could instead is add a text box instead of input control so that you will be able to find the text box control in the code behind.

Comment: But sir, I will need to display more than values in single row (may two labels or one label and one text box in single column) so how would I get the exact output? @user3240361